# Adding quotes to string before execution?

Tags: bash

So I have a string representing a path:

```
string="/Volumes/Media/James Blake - Digital Lion [V0] 2013"
```

I want to perform:

```
cd $string

#do some work..
```

This won't work because the directory has spaces and brackets that bash doesn't like.

So my first thought was to change the string to :

```
/Volumes/Media/James\ Blake\ -\ Digital\ Lion\ \[V0\]\ 2013/
```

However in terminal simply doing:

```
cd "/Volumes/Media/Transmission/Finished/James Blake - Digital Lion [V0] 2013" works just fine.
```

So I wonder is there a way to add quotes to each end of the string and actually execute the command with the quotes?

Answer (score 3):

`cd "$string"`

Always surround variables with quotes (unless there's a good reason not to) because it helps you avoid this exact scenario.